# Can we build a custom login page to send the username and password to AD FS 2016 instead of using the OOB page

Tags: c#, adfs

Our customer have a custom login page that contains username and password, login with social account as FB, Twitter and a custom login way for them. they want to use the ADFS 2016 on premises and the OOB login page is not an option for their public site. please advise if it is doable and if yes if there is any blog or steps we can follow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

No - it is not doable.

There are no ADFS authentication API that allow this.